# Can't open an MVC3 project in VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I just installed visual studio 2012 professional (with Blend) and now I can't open a .NET MVC3 web project. The project does not load and says it is incompatible, despite the fact that other developers working on the same codebase are using VS2012 with no issue.

Furthermore, when I go to Solution -> Add -> New Project, I don't see the option to add a web project that I did with VS2010. This makes me think that I am missing some kind of web developer setting, extension, or add-in, but I can't figure out how to install that.

How can I fix my visual studio (or project) setup to allow me to open this project?

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to have installed a web version of visual studio.

I'm guessing you installed the Express version of either the Windows 8 Edition (which creates Windows 8 apps) or the Windows Desktop version (or maybe Windows Phone version).

If this is the express edition, download and install the Web Edition.  If this is a Professional or higher version, then you may not have installed the right components.

Comment: This is a professional edition. How do I go about switching which components are installed? Do I need to do a full reinstall? Which components do I need?

Comment: @ChaseMedallion - Go into Programs and Features in Windows, find VS in the list, click the change button, click on the modify button of the setup app that starts, make sure Microsoft Web Developer Tools is selected and click OK.  If it is selected, you may need to uninstall and re-install.